# Storing data in an object. Which method is faster?

Tags: php, optimization

Hi I recently saw [this article](http://www.webmaster-source.com/2009/08/20/php-stdclass-storing-data-object-instead-array/) on how to store data into objects:

```
$profile = new stdClass;
$profile->first_name = 'Woppi';
$profile->last_name = 'Jillenjack';
$profile->email = 'woppi.jillenjack@gmail.com';
```

I'm used to making it an array then typecasting it to object (before I read the article):

```
$profile = array('first_name'=>'Woppi', 'last_name'=>'Jillenjack', 'email'=>'woppi.jillenjack@gmail.com');
$profile = (object)$profile;
```

I'm thinking the first method is faster. How do I know which is faster... can you suggest a way I can find this out?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Two things: a) I can't believe people are actually concerned by the speed of object construction. b) Do whatever is clearer for an external reader c) How difficult is it to benchmark on your own? d) That was 4 things.

Comment: Well if you have thousand of these operations per second it would really mater. Also if you are creating some kind of open source library which you would like to publish you would like to make it perfect. I am a perfectionist and I believe that it really does matters.

Comment: @Cicada I have a lot to learn... I'm just curious... that's all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if you are running PHP on Linux you can measure the time to run each method with [microtime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php)
* Windows won't return correct time but an approximation. That won't really help you if you are trying to measure something in microseconds.

Also I believe that the second method should be faster because it will use an integrated function written in C, instead of interpreting several lines of PHP code and then executing them.

So I vote for the second one. You can still have some fun with measuring how much time it will take for each method.

Comment: You're right I just did the microtime thing. :) The typecasting is faster. http://codepad.org/2M8SrO19

Comment: I'm sad, how is possible that a type casting be faster than a creation of a instantiation of a class and add variables?. In theory, internally the casting needs to do the creation of a stdClass object and after parsing the data...

Comment: @Woppi just change order of these tests and you will see that typecasting is slower :D add loop or something to get it more accurate

Answer (score 1):

In both cases you need to create a instance of a class (stdClass or Array) and set the data. In the second case you add a new operation, the cast, therefore exists implicit the creation of an stdClass instance and the parsing data operation from Array to stdClass.

In first case, you only create a instance of a class, in the second are create both, but 1 is invisible to the programmer. I think that the first is more efficient in memory and speed

```
  1 <?php                                                                                                                                                                          
  2                                                                                
  3  $time_start = microtime(true);                                                
  4                                                                                
  5 for($i=0 ; $i<1000000; $i++)                                                   
  6 {                                                                              
  7  $profile = new stdClass;$                                                      
  8  $profile->first_name = 'Woppi';                                               
  9  $profile->last_name = 'Jillenjack';                                           
 10  $profile->email = 'woppi.jillenjack@gmail.com';                               
 11  $time_end = microtime(true);$                                                  
 12 }                                                                              
 13                                                                                
 14  $object = $time_end - $time_start;                                            
 15                                                                                
 16                                                                               
 17  $time_start = microtime(true);                                               
 18  for($i=0;$i<1000000;$i++)                                                     
 19  {                                                                             
 20  $profile = array('first_name'=>'Woppi',                                      
 21          'last_name'=>'Jillenjack',                                            
 22          'email'=>'woppi.jillenjack@gmail.com');                               
 23  $profile = (object)$profile;                                                  
 24  $time_end = microtime(true);                                                  
 25  }                                                                             
 26  $array_to_object = $time_end - $time_start;                                   
 27                                                                                
 28  echo "stdClass: $object | Typecasting: $array_to_object";                     
 29                                                                              
 30 ?>
```

stdClass: 10.045720100403 | Typecasting: 10.009358882904

stdClass: 9.9519069194794 | Typecasting: 9.2100629806519

stdClass: 9.2515120506287 | Typecasting: 9.480808019638

stdClass: 9.5376181602478 | Typecasting: 9.2310011386871

stdClass: 9.9628109931946 | Typecasting: 10.414475917816

The test is not conclusive, in this case maybe the memory consumed help us to make a choice for use one or other